# angularJS $location.url adds the url at the end of current one

Tags: angularjs

**SOLVED**
the trick was using window.location = '....';

I'm new to the AngularJS and I'm experiencing problems with redirecting after saving form data.

when I click 'Save' button, I send the data to the server, which saves it to the database.

```
$scope.save = function (trips) {
    if (trips.length != 0) {
        tripsRepositorySave.save(trips).then(function () {
            $location.url('/Trips?id=' + trips[0].id);
        });
    }
};
```

this is the tripsRepositorySave

```
app.factory('tripsRepositorySave', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    save: function (trips) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post('/Trips/Save', trips).success(function () { deferred.resolve(); });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
})
```

and the result is this url

```
http://localhost:3333/Trips?assignmentID=2#/Trips?assignmentID=2
```

I cant manage to make it rewrite the whole path, I have tried $location.path, $scope.apply() and everything i could google, but the result is still the same.

Another thing is that I want the page to get reloaded as well and it doesnt seem to be happening.

Thank you for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Andy Gaskell answer.

$location.url(...) will manage only part after '#'. So your code works as expected.
If you want to reload full page use [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) or [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
$location.path("/Trips").search('id', trips[0].id);
```

Also see the hash function if you need to append a hash.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: I was trying to get rid of the hash and just rewrite the whole path and reload it :) window.location worked :)

Comment: Yeah `window.location` should break out of your angular app, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: well, after i save/add all the items i want to reload the page so it loads all the data again with IDs etc. maybe my whole approach is wrong..? so far i need to use angular only at one page so i didnt set up any routing or anything

Comment: If this works for you then awesome, but generally that is not the angular way of doing things. Good luck!